# Middleware called twice

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

I implemented a middleware en .net core to read the request and verify if the attributeody of  name is contained 2 times in the body of the request. I am getting grazy, I cannot figure out how is it possible the middleware is being called twice and the second time returns a 500 status error code. I only added the middleware once to the startup.cs, but anything I try is not working and the middleware is called twice, second one with an error. Please, help

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var request = context.Request;

    if (request.Method != HttpMethods.Post)
    {
        await _next(context);
        return;
    }

    var requestBody = await ReadRequestBody(request);

    if (Validation(requestBody))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Duplicated fields");
        return;
    }

    request.Body = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody));

    await _next(context);
    return;
}
```

STARTUP.CS

```
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<SingleOccurrenceMiddleware>();

            if (env.EnvironmentName != "Local")
                app.UseHsts();

            app.UseXRay("UKIAwardsCampaigns");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            #region NetCore 3.1 Middlewares migration
            //Setup Cors from EnvironmentVar
            app.UseCorsFromEnvironmentVar("ASPNETCORE_CORS_URLs");

            app.UseAuthentication();

            //Add a middleware to build a EnterpriseIdentity from a claims Identity
            app.UseEnterpriseIdentity();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            #endregion

            app.UseLocalization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code and seen where the exception occurs and looked at the stack how you got into the method that is then surfaced as 500? That should give you hints why there is a second call. We need more context to get away from guessing (like there is a second request you don't expect without a body that you expect).

Comment: @Ralf. I debugged the code and in the first call I dont reach the controller, but in the second one I do reach. The error looks like something related to get information of other repository from the modular API that I dont launch yet. But it is strange, when I dont use this middleware, I dont have any problem to get any data from other repositories in Development environment. Do you need any extra information? Please, ask me

Comment: How is the middleware registered? Post enough information so *we* can reproduce the error. `from other repositories` ASP.NET Core doesn't have repositories, so what does this mean? What is the *middleware* trying to achieve? JSON doesn't allow duplicate attributes so simply posting such a thing should result in a validation error. What's the output want to validate? And since this is a validation issue, why not use [the built in options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#alternatives-to-built-in-attributes)?

Comment: The built-in options will return a standard ValidationProblemDetails result that can be handled by clients and use less memory than caching the entire response in memory twice.

Comment: It's also possible the *client* has more bugs than sending invalid JSON, like sending *empty* requests. Duplicate keys is 100% a client bug. An empty body is *not* invalid but certainly unexpected. When CORS is used, a client is supposed to send an OPTIONS request to ask the server what's permitted, then make the POST request. If the client is so buggy it sends duplicate JSON keys, perhaps it's sending POST instead of OPTIONS too?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. I posted how the middleware is registered. My API is modular, each project reach its respository through the call through the controller. In this example, The middleware reachs its repository and settings repository. But settings repository returns a 500 error. When I make a call without use middleware, the call reachs its repository besides settings repository without any problem. I dont know what is happening....

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. The middleware code is made to avoid call with the attribute name twice in body. It is just to avoid this kind of call by postman, just for security purposes. Our code only can accept GET and POST methods for the same reason.

Comment: Is `app.UseMiddleware<SingleOccurrenceMiddleware>();` the call that adds the middleware? That's way, way too high. The order matters and that middleware is called even before HTTPS

Comment: `avoid call with the attribute name twice in body` again, doesn't ASP.NET Core reject that during binding? Adding extra code "just in case" *reduces* security. In this case, the incorrect registration *and* the middleware code introduces security issues by interfering with HTTPS *and* loading the entire request in memory before ASP.NET Core had a chance to inspect and discard invalid requests, like huge or infinite requests. This opens up the possibility of a DoS attach by posting huge or infinite streams of garbage

Comment: The fact the middleware is called before authentication means that anonymous clients can carry out the DoS attack too. Such a middleware only affects endpoints, so it should be either right above `MapEndpoints` or act as an endpoint filter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Can you give an example? I tried with Action Filter, but I couldn´t make it run.

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing this *at all*? Doesn't ASP.NET Core itself detect the invalid JSON when it tries to deserialize the payload? If you check the [Filters documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you'll see that Action filters are called *after* model binding which means ASP.NET Core has already rejected any invalid requests with a 400.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. When I use JSON approach, It just takes the last one of the value of each attribute name repeated. I want to detect when There are more than one and return an error 400 with message Attribute name duplicated.

Comment: I think you should place Usemiddleware<> after Cors and UseAuthirization in configuration.

Comment: @PouyaHashemi. Tried it, still not working

Comment: Its the expected behavior executing a middleware twice because when http request executes usually two endpoints get hit. So the middleware executed twice.

Comment: No worries, its absolutely fine and expected. So your application code is alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I implemented a middleware en .net core to read the request and verify
> if the attributeody of name is contained 2 times in the body of the
> request.

Actually, this is the expected behavior when executing a middleware twice because when an HTTP request executes usually two endpoints get hit. So the middleware executes twice.

If you debug your application, you would observe that first call  would be executed for loading your application itself the base path should be your domain/local host or `/`.

And for the second time, your application has its resouce file. For instance, css, js or any other internal file within your application root folder which need additional execution.

Please have a look at the following network trace log:

[image]

[image]

Therefore, you can check out your 500 error what causing this, but apart from 500 internal error, middleware execution twice is not a downsides.